# Should session tokens not expire, provided they are still being used?

Tags: rest, security, token, backend

I'm developing a backend API. When the frontend API first connects it sends credentials to the /initialise endpoint. It gets back a token that is used to authenticate itself in the future. Every 30 seconds the frontend sends a "I'm still here" message that updates when the token was last used. This is the same for every other endpoint that uses the token - it updates when the token was last used. If the token hasn't been used in 120 seconds I expire it and end the session. Is this secure?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this secure?

This is a very subjective question. As you describe it, a token's validity could be infinite as long as the front-end keeps sending a keep-alive or a heartbeat request to your back-end. This is a potential security concern. A more secure design is to have a token expire every `x` quanta {`seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`, `days`}.

I will present a couple of questions for you to think about your overall design:

- How abstracted and secure is the front-end api call (to the back-end) and token caching mechanism? (Asking this from the perspective of a malicious user being able to attain these easily thus being able to manipulate your back-end)
- Can you think of a design that uses another layer of authentication (in addition to the token issue and caching mechanism). Examples include: random code generators that are known to both the front-end and back-end, certificate verification, etc. With every layer of authentication you reduce the chances of compromising your back-end exponentially.